# sed to replace variable string in Unix ksh

Tags: sed, ksh

One of my file abc.txt contains below path as one of the line.

```
/lz/BEN_BOB.success
```

It is to be replaced as below

```
/lz/BEN_B.success
```

I'm generating these names during runtime hence storing in variables as below.

```
SUCCESS_FILE=/lz/BEN_BOB.success
NEW_SUCCESS_FILE=/lz/BEN_B.success
```

I'm using below command to replace but not working.

```
cat abc.txt | sed "s/$SUCCESS_FILE/$NEW_SUCCESS_FILE/g".
```

Is it because I have `/` symbol in variables?

As mentioned it is in korn shell.

Comment: avoid [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: Removed cat and use direct sed on filename.  Same wrong output

Comment: yup, both are equivalent command, just that you didn't need to use `cat`

Comment: True. Please provide me the solution for given problem.

Comment: The answer of @oliv seems right. Can you `echo "SUCCESS_FILE=${SUCCESS_FILE}"`? Maybe the runtime generation (in a subshell?) went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another delimiter in your sed command (e.g. `|` instead of `/`):

```
sed "s|$SUCCESS_FILE|$NEW_SUCCESS_FILE|g" abc.txt
```

Comment: then please update your question with the real content of file `abc.txt`